# Want to apply unique css for a particular item

Tags: javascript, antd

[image]

Want to apply `max width` to the insurance field value using `antd form` Item.

```html
<Form.Item label="Insurance Name" name="InsuranceName">
  {records.Table3.length !== 0 && records.Table3[0].InsuranceName}
</Form.Item>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give a className to your Form Item:

```
<Form.Item label="Insurance Name" name="InsuranceName" className="myClass">
    {records.Table3.length !== 0 && records.Table3[0].InsuranceName}
</Form.Item>;
```

And use it to style the form item content :

```
.myClass > .ant-form-item-control-input-content {
    max-width: 30px;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/tanguyroberjot/pen/YzZPvgJ?editors=0110) is a working codepen